Seeking strong bounds on KL-divergence and martingales for a hypothesis-testing inequality
Let's say we have a finite set $\mathcal{O}$ of observations, and let $\mathcal{C}(\Delta\mathcal{O})$ denote the space of closed convex sets of probability distributions.
We have two hypotheses which we are trying to distinguish, $\mu:\mathbb{N}\to\Delta\mathcal{O}$, and $\Psi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{C}(\Delta\mathcal{O})$. $\mu$ is saying "on the i'th time step, the outcome will be sampled from $\mu_{i}$", and $\Psi$ is saying "on the i'th time step, the outcome will be sampled from one of the probability distributions within $\Psi_{i}$, but I don't know which one. The choice of probability distribution that reality plays may depend in a complicated way on the past history". We would like to learn which hypothesis is true, from observation.
Unfortunately, getting a good result along these lines has turned out to be difficult.
For other notation, $o_i$ will be used for the i'th observation, and $s_i\in\Psi_{i}$ is the probability distribution which reality samples $o_i$ from, and can depend arbitrarily on the past history. $\nu^{*}_i$ is the information projection of $\mu_i$ to $\Psi_i$. Ie, we have
$$\nu^{*}_{i}=\text{argmin}_{\nu\in\Psi_{i}}D_{KL}(\nu|\mu_i)$$
Now, the quantity
$$\sum_{i=1}^{T}\ln\left(\frac{\nu^{*}_{i}}{\mu_i}(o_i)\right)$$
is important because it can be thought of as the cumulative evidence (in nats) for $\Psi$ after $T$ turns. It would be nice to get a $1-\delta$-style lower bound on this quantity, if $\Psi$ does indeed happen to be true (true in this case means that, on each turn, the distribution $s_i$ that $o_i$ is sampled from is selected from $\Psi_i$, possibly in a way that depends on past history). Something of the form "if $\mu_i$ keeps being far from $\Psi_i$, and $\Psi$ is true, then with high probability, the above sum is large/there's lots of evidence for $\Psi$". Specifically, I'm hunting for a lower bound expressed in terms of
$$\sum_{i=1}^{T}\min_{\nu\in\Psi_i}D^{2}_{H}(\mu_i,\nu)$$
Where $D^{2}_{H}$ is the squared Hellinger distance. Also $\ln\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)$ is expected to appear in the bound.
But Why Would We Expect This to Hold?
There are three "almost-proofs" of this conjecture, which all involve handwaving away a critical step, yet I cannot prove it in full generality. The arguments are as follows.
First, the "handwave away the martingale complications" argument. Namely,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{T}\ln\left(\frac{\nu^{*}_{i}}{\mu_i}(o_i)\right)\simeq\sum_{i=1}^{T}\mathbb{E}_{s_i}\left[\ln\left(\frac{\nu^{*}_{i}}{\mu_i}\right)\right]\ge\sum_{i=1}^{T}\mathbb{E}_{\nu^{*}_i}\left[\ln\left(\frac{\nu^{*}_{i}}{\mu_i}\right)\right]$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{T}D_{KL}(\nu^{*}_i|\mu_i)\ge\sum_{i=1}^{T}D^{2}_{H}(\nu^{*}_i,\mu_i)\ge\sum_{i=1}^{T}\min_{\nu\in\Psi_i}D^{2}_{H}(\mu_i,\nu)$$
The approximate equality is where we handwave away martingale complications. The first inequality comes from the wikipedia page on information projection, where we observe that we can rearrange wikipedia's equation of $D_{KL}(s_i|\mu_i)\ge D_{KL}(s_i|\nu^{*}_i)+D_{KL}(\nu^{*}_i|\mu_i)$ into $D_{KL}(s_i|\mu_i)-D_{KL}(s_i|\nu^{*}_i)\ge D_{KL}(\nu^{*}_i|\mu_i)$ and observe that the left-hand side equals the $\mathbb{E}_{s_i}\left[\ln\left(\frac{\nu^{*}_{i}}{\mu_i}\right)\right]$ term of interest. The next equality is just packing up definitions, the inequality after that uses that KL-divergence exceeds squared Hellinger distance, $D_{KL}\ge D^{2}_{H}$, and the last inequality is obvious.
However, the log of information ratios is a difficult quantity to apply martingale arguments to. Azuma, Bernstein, Freedman, and more, fail to apply because there are no obvious upper or lower bounds on its value, so we can't eliminate the handwaving part.
Second, the "handwave away that $\Psi_i$ is a set instead of a point" argument. This argument comes from Lemma A.4 and Lemma A.14 of Foster. Pages 70 and 79 contain the relevant proofs. Roughly, the way it goes is that Lemma A.4 uses some magical martingale shenanigans to establish that with $1-\delta$ probability, we have
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{T}\ln\left(\frac{\nu^{*}_{i}}{\mu_i}(o_i)\right)+\ln\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)\ge-\sum_{i=1}^{T}\ln\left(\mathbb{E}_{s_i}\left[e^{\frac{-1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\nu^{*}_{i}}{\mu_i}\right)}\right]\right)$$
The right-hand side simplifies to
$$-\sum_{i=1}^{T}\ln\left(\mathbb{E}_{s_i}\left[\sqrt{\frac{\mu_i}{\nu^{*}_i}}\right]\right)$$
Now, if the set $\Psi_i$, which $s_i$ was selected from, is a point (it isn't), then we have $s_i=\nu^{*}_i$, and can proceed to
$$=-\sum_{i=1}^{T}\ln\left(\mathbb{E}_{\nu^{*}_i}\left[\sqrt{\frac{\mu_i}{\nu^{*}_i}}\right]\right)=-\sum_{i=1}^{T}\ln\left(\sum_{o\in\mathcal{O}}\sqrt{\mu_i(o)\nu^{*}_i(o)}\right)$$
$$=-\sum_{i=1}^{T}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{2}D^{2}_{H}(\mu_i,\nu^{*}_i)\right)\ge\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{T}D^{2}_{H}(\mu_i,\nu^{*}_i)$$
In order, we assumed that $s_i=\nu^{*}_i$, unpacked the expectation and cancelled, packed up the definition of squared Hellinger distance, and used that $-\ln(1-x)\ge x$. Just multiply the start and end of the inequality chain by 2, and you're good to go! Except for the part where $\Psi$ produces closed convex sets instead of points. Ugh.
Time for attempt 3, the "handwave away that the KL-distance minimizer isn't the Hellinger distance minimizer" argument. Use $\nu^{H}_i$ for the point in $\Psi_i$ that minimizes Hellinger distance to $\mu_i$. This point may differ from $\nu^{*}_i$, but is at least Hellinger-close to $\nu^{*}_i$. It starts off as normal, with us applying Lemma A.4 from Foster, and then we handwavily assume
$$-\sum_{i=1}^{T}\ln\left(\mathbb{E}_{s_i}\left[\sqrt{\frac{\mu_i}{\nu^{*}_i}}\right]\right)\simeq-\sum_{i=1}^{T}\ln\left(\mathbb{E}_{s_i}\left[\sqrt{\frac{\mu_i}{\nu^{H}_i}}\right]\right)$$
At this point, we can observe that
$$\mathbb{E}_{s_i}\left[\sqrt{\frac{\mu_i}{\nu^{H}_i}}\right]\le\mathbb{E}_{\nu^{H}_i}\left[\sqrt{\frac{\mu_i}{\nu^{H}_i}}\right]$$
The proof of this above fact is not entirely trivial, but roughly, it happens because the above square root is the derivative of "negative Hellinger-squared distance from $\mu_i$" evaluated at $\nu^{H}_i$. Traveling from $\nu^{H}_i$ towards $s_i$ involves the negative Hellinger-squared distance going down (since $\nu^{H}_i$ is the Hellinger-closest point to $\mu_i$ that lives in $\Psi_i$, and $s_i$ also lives in $\Psi_i$, and $\Psi_i$ is convex), so the derivative slopes downwards in that direction, so $\nu^{H}_i$ is the maximizer of the above square root within $\Psi_i$. And then we can go
$$-\sum_{i=1}^{T}\ln\left(\mathbb{E}_{s_i}\left[\sqrt{\frac{\mu_i}{\nu^{H}_i}}\right]\right)\ge-\sum_{i=1}^{T}\ln\left(\mathbb{E}_{\nu^{H}_i}\left[\sqrt{\frac{\mu_i}{\nu^{H}_i}}\right]\right)$$
And clean up the rest of the argument as we did with the "imagine $\Psi_i$ is a point" argument.
Lamentably, none of these three arguments is a proper proof, and all require unacceptable amounts of handwaving.
Additional Tools That Came Up In Literature Review
I haven't figured out how to apply any of these results yet, but they feel as though they may plausibly be important to a proper proof.
Sanov's Theorem, which basically says that given a set of probability distributions, and a true probability distribution, the empirical average has a low probability of being in the set of probability distributions, and that probability is controlled by the KL divergence of the true probability distribution to your set of interest.
Rohit Agrawal's Theorem 1.5, which contains the same sort of "log of expectation of exponent of KL-divergence" term as Lemma A.4 of Foster gives you, and connects it to "log of expectation of exponent of expected KL-divergence". Note that this latter term may let us connect the $\mathbb{E}_{s_i}\ln\left(\frac{\nu^{*}_i}{\mu_i}\right)\ge\mathbb{E}_{\nu^{*}_i}\ln\left(\frac{\nu^{*}_i}{\mu_i}\right)$ inequality from the first failed proof (which didn't show up in the latter two failed proofs), with the near-success of the other two failed proofs. It may be a powerful result if I can just figure out how to translate it to this different setting.
